# Find a group $G$ with $a\in G$ such that $|a|=6$ but $C_G(a)\neq C_G(a^3)$.

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, alternative-proof, dihedral-groups

This is part of Exercise 46 of Chapter 3 of Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra"*.

> **Notation 1:** The centraliser of $g$ in a group $G$ is denoted $C_G(g)$.
>
> **Notation 2:** The dihedral group $D_n$ has order $2n$.

I'm interested in how one would answer the following question **using the tools available in the textbook prior to it.**

> Find a group $G$ with $a\in G$ such that $|a|=6$ but $C_G(a)\neq C_G(a^3)$.

*NOTE:* The textbook doesn't cover permutation groups prior to this.

*Thoughts:*

- I understand that the group $H$ given by the presentation $$\langle a, x\mid a^6, a^3x=xa^3\rangle$$ would suffice as $x\in C_H(a^3)\setminus C_H(a)$ *by construction*; however, presentations aren't covered in the preceding material. It's not clear to me how I would exploit my understanding of this perspective to construct/name a group in the spirit of the question.
- Perhaps a dihedral group $D_n$ would do for some $n$ s.t. $6\mid n$ but I'm not sure. These groups are defined in terms of reflections & rotations in the text, but the way I see them is, again, as in terms of a few different presentations for them. [*From my comment below:*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3059566/find-a-group-g-with-g-in-g-s-t-a-6-but-c-ga-neq-c-ga3#comment6308737_3059566) The problem is that it's defined in terms of a regular $n$-gon in this textbook. I'm used to just using a presentation. **If I'm to use $D_6$ here, then I'm to argue from the perspective of the book; I'm not so sure how to proceed.** (Emphasis added.)

Please help :)

Comment: Have you tried the dihedral group $D_6$ of order 12?

Comment: @DerekHolt Not yet. I'm on it now. The problem is that it's defined in terms of a regular $n$-gon in this textbook. I'm used to just using a presentation. If I'm to use $D_6$ here, then I'm to argue from the perspective of the book; I'm not so sure how to proceed.

Comment: @Shaun I suspect that reasoning from the geometry will be easier than reasoning from the presentation.

Comment: How so, @EthanBolker?

Comment: Let $a$ be a rotation through $60^\circ$. Then $a$ has order $6$ and does not commute with a reflection. But $a^3$ is a rotation through $180^\circ$ and does commute with all reflections - it lies in the centrel of $D_6$.

Comment: Because  thinking geometrically you can identify the orders of all the elements at a glance: flips have order $2$, rotations $2$ or $3$ or $6$.  This information is buried when you use the presentation.  See @DerekHolt 's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already covered the symmetric groups $S_n$ in your course? If you can use them, then an idea could be to employ the fact that non-overlapping cycles commute with each other. For example, if $a$ is a product of two independent cycles of lengths $2$ and $3$, then the latter one will disappear in $a^3$, and thus its centralizer will be different.

Comment: No, they're not covered in the book so far. I have plenty of experience with them though. Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: May I ask why the downvote?

Comment: Because symmetric groups aren't covered by the book so far. It's my fault for not making that (abundantly) clear, so I'm sorry.

Comment: It was a helpful answer nonetheless, I don't think the downvote is fair. You only specified that you would like to use the tools available to you, but not really which set of tools you have. You instead can choose to not vote.

Comment: Answers should address the question as asked. If somebody finds a question unsuitable they are free not to answer it, and even to vote negatively on the question. What is not alright is to answer the question that one would like to answer (even if it is a reasonable one). The restriction to answer an exercise from a text in the way(s) intended is a coherent restriction. It'd  been better to be right away more explicit, but **"I'm interested in how one would answer the following question using the tools available in the text prior to it."** is in principle clear (though implicit).

Comment: I've seen the book, and in that chapter he has only seen **abelian** groups, but the dihedral, but it seems he does not understand the representation given in the book

Comment: @quid: I agree! But that note was added by the OP way after the two answers with permutation groups (mine and another one) had already been posted. At the time of answering it wasn't there. I have no problem admitting that my response doesn't provide a desired answer to the question. But receiving a downvote still seems a bit unfair to me.

Comment: @zipirovich it was there [in the very first revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3059566/1) It is possible that the absolutely first version did not contain it as there is a grace period for edits, but it definitely was there well before an answer was given.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D_{12}$ be the dihedral group, presented as follows
$$D_{12}=\left\langle x,y\;:\;x^2=y^6=1,\quad xyx=y^{-1}\right\rangle.$$
Consider $a=y$, it is easy to see that its order is $6$. Now, we have that $xyx=y^{-1}\neq y$ but $xy^3x=y^{-3}=y^3$ (note that $x=x^{-1}$). Therefore, $x$ lies on the centrlizer of $y^3$ but not in the centralizer of $y$.

---

*Not covered in the preceding material but:*

Consider $G=S_8$ the symmetric group. Let $\sigma=(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)$ be a permutation, it is clear that $|\sigma|=6$, note that $\sigma^3=(1 4)$. We  have that $(5\ 6)$ lies in the centralizer of $\sigma^3$ but does not lie on the centralizer of $\sigma$.

Comment: Permutation groups aren't covered in the textbook prior to the question.

Comment: Why are you studying a introductory book that does not cover that :S

Comment: It does, just **not yet**.

Comment: I will edit and add an alternative. If it doen't work a diheldral group, the problems should not be in that part of the text

Comment: I'm afraid presentations aren't covered either. Also, see my questions second bullet point.

Comment: For me $D_{2n}$ has order $2n$

Comment: I've reviewed your book, and it studies the dihedral group, and if you look closer you can deduce this representation (he is using representations in a hidden way)

Comment: It's a *presentation*, not a **re**presentation. But fair enough.

Comment: My bad. But it's not hard to develop that. I recommend you to "play" more with dihedral groups, anyways, it will be important as examples in your studies

Comment: I think you made a mistake here, because there are only two elements of order 6 in that dihedral group: $y$ and $y^{-1}$.

Comment: What's the mistake?

Comment: Hmmm... In $D_{12}$, $xyx=y^{-1}$ hence $a^2=(xy)^2=(xyx)y=e$ hence the order of $a$ is **not** $6$.

Comment: Sorry, $a=y$, I typed $x$ as error

Comment: I've corrected the misspell